# How to handle a post before publishing?

Tags: posts, publish, regex

I want to do a regex match to each post before it gets published, and if the regex fails to match, delete the post entirely, what hook should I use?

Answer (score 0):

You need this filter:

```
function add_myself($content){
    return $content." myself";
}
add_filter('content_save_pre','add_myself');
```

Found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4147860/982517

Comment: This doesn't cover how to delete post though, which is probably tricky to do while it is saving.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this. I tested it and it worked. I don't know how stable it is, so you should do some testing for yourself:

```
function rsp_remove_post_while_saving($post_id) {
    remove_action( 'save_post', 'rsp_remove_post_while_saving', 13, 2 );
    wp_trash_post($post_id);
}

function add_myself($content){
    // if your post is not valid {
        add_action( 'save_post', 'rsp_remove_post_while_saving' );
    // }
}
add_filter('content_save_pre','add_myself');
```